# A User unit test always passes in case of Null, Undefined, True and False

Tags: node.js, express, jestjs

I am unit testing a Nodejs User model with Jest. Here is the code for model:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const config = require('config');
const moment = require('moment');
const Joi = require('joi');
const Sql = require('sequelize');
const db = require("../startup/db");

const User = db.define('user', {
    id: {type: Sql.INTEGER,
         primaryKey:true,
         min: 1},
    name: {type: Sql.STRING,
           allowNull: false,
           min: 2,
           max: 50,
    },
    email: {type: Sql.STRING,
            isEmail: true
    },      
    cell: {type: Sql.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            unique:true,  //cell number is universally unique 
            min: 10,
            max: 20,
    },
    cell_country_code: {type: Sql.STRING,
    },
    customer_id: {type: Sql.INTEGER,
                  allowNull: false,
    },
    role: {type: Sql.STRING},
    last_updated_by_id: {type: Sql.INTEGER},
    fort_token: {type: Sql.STRING,
                 allowNull: false,
    },
    createdAt: Sql.DATE,
    updatedAt: Sql.DATE
  }, {
    validate: {async custom_validate() {
      let user = await User.findOne({where:{name :req.body.name, fort_token: session('fort_token')}});
      if (user) return res.status(400).send("用户重名！");

    }
  }
});

function validateUser(user) {
    const schema = {
        name: Joi.string()
        .min(2)
        .max(50)
        .required()
        .trim(),
    cell: Joi.string()
        .min(10)
        .max(20)
        .trim()
        .required()
        .error(new Error('该手机号有误！')),
    email: Joi.string()
        .min(5)
        .max(255)
        .email()
        .error(new Error('邮件地址格式不对！'))
        .trim(),
    customer_id: Joi.integer()
        .required(),
    fort_token: Joi.string()
        .required(),
    };

    return Joi.validate(user, schema);
};
```

Here is the test case. When a user can have duplicate name if the fort_token is different:

```
const {User} = require('../../../models/user');
const moment = require('moment');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const config = require('config');
const Sql = require("sequelize");

describe('User model should be sound', () => {
    let name = 'john doe';
    let customer_id = 1;
    let cell = '1234567890';
    let fort_token = '12349596874567678906';
    let role = 'admin';
    let expire_datetime =  moment().add(24, 'hours');
    let email = 'home@yahoo.com';

    let payload = () =>{ 
        return {
          customer_id: customer_id,
          name:  name,
          cell: cell,
          email: email,
          expire_datetime: expire_datetime,
          role: role,
          fort_token: fort_token
        }};

     it('should allow duplicate name with different fort token and cell', () => {
        let user = new User(payload());
        name = user.name;
        cell = user.cell + '1';
        fort_token = user.fort_token + '1';
        let user1 = new User(payload());
        expect(user1).toBeNull; 
   });
```

The unit test passes with green. I tried to test with the following:

```
expect(user1).toBeTruthy;
expect(user1).toBeFalsy;
expect(user1).toBeUndefined;
```

To my big surprise, all passes with green. I don't quite get it why the `user1` object could be all `truthy, falsy, Null and Undefined`  at the same time! Or should I use `toHaveProperty()` to test object?

Comment: Do you use `jest`? If so, you should execute it's methods to do an assertion, i.e. `expect(user1).toBeTruthy()`, `expect(user1).toBeFalsy()`, etc

Comment: Yes, it is jest 4.42.

Comment: Does adding parentheses `()` at the end of each expectation help then?

Comment: I tried and it did not help with (). For example, the new User(payload()) created a user with a name of 'a' which is shorter than 2. An error was expected with a shorter name and should not return any user object. I don't have the db created for the test and am sure that it would be OK for unit test.

Answer (score 0):

I think in order to get the expected results you should use the following codes:

```
expect(user1).to.be.true
expect(user1).to.be.false
expect(user1).to.be.undefined
```

You should take a look at the offical [Chai Documentation](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/)